# Set leaf node value as an attribute

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have this type of XML file (test.xml):

```
<product>
  <node>
    <region_id>
      <node>1</node>
    </region_id>
    <region_time>
      <node>27</node>
      <node>02</node>
      <node>2013</node>
    </region_time>
    <tab_id>351</tab_id>
    <product_id>1</product_id>
    <tab_name>test1</tab_name>
  </node>
</product>
```

I want to change in them in like something this type:

```
<product>
  <region_id>1</region_id>
  <region_time>27,02,2013</region_time>
  <tab_id value="351"></tab_id>
  <product_id value="1"></product_id>
  <tab_name value="test1"></tab_name>
</product>
```

Here I am using `XSLT` `PHP`

My XSLT code (test.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- from dimitre\'s xsl.thanks -->
 <xsl:template match="node[position()>1]/text()">
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*xslt.php*

```
$sourcedoc = new DOMDocument();
$sourcedoc->load('test.xml');

$stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
$stylesheet->load('test.xsl');

// create a new XSLT processor and load the stylesheet
$xsltprocessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltprocessor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

// save the new xml file
file_put_contents('test-translated.xml', $xsltprocessor->transformToXML($sourcedoc));
```

With this code O/P is:

```
<product>
  <region_id>1</region_id>
  <region_time>27,02,2013</region_time>
  </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  </tab_name>
</product>
```

Not given `<tab_id> <product_id>` and `<tab_name>`

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `<xsl:template>` element like this should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="tab_id | product_id | tab_name">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```